# FileNames not containing a given extension

Tags: string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I would like to get all the files in a directory *without* a given extension. To get them with that extension is quite simple:

```
FileNames["*.<myExt>", myDir]
```

But instead I want everything *except* `"*.<myExt>"` and for reasons beyond the purview of this question I can't just post-process.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Actually your problem can be solved in a straightforward way using [Negative Lookbehind After the Match](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#negative-lookbehind) assertion with [End of String](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#dollar) anchor. Note however that PCRE supports only fixed-length lookbehind, so you can't exclude a list of extensions with different lengths *using only one lookbehind assertion*. The solution is to include separate assertion for every extension.

I also think that the restriction `[^\\.]` in your regex is superfluous (unless you really wish to exclude filenames containing the dot `\\.` *before* the extension's dot).

Here is an example regex excluding only filenames with `n` extension (but including `nb`, `nbp` etc. and also filenames without extension):

```
RegularExpression[".+(?<!\\.n)$"]
```

And here is an example regex excluding only filenames with `n` and `nb` extensions (but including `nbp`, `png` etc. and also filenames without extension):

```
RegularExpression[".+(?<!\\.n)(?<!\\.nb)$"]
```

---

The same problem can be solved using string patterns.

Here is a `StringExpression` which excludes only filenames with extension `n`  (i.e. includes `nb`, `nbp` etc. and also filenames without extension):

```
name__ ~~ EndOfString /; StringTake[name, -2] =!= ".n"
```

And here is a version which excludes only filenames with extensions `n` and `nb`:

```
name__ ~~ EndOfString /;
 StringTake[name, -2] =!= ".n" &&
  StringTake[name, -3] =!= ".nb"
```

Another version:

```
name__ ~~ EndOfString /; ! MatchQ[FileExtension[name], "n" | "nb"]
```

Comment: Problem with `StringExpression` is that `FileNames` doesn't handle it right.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Have you tried my version? I've checked with the example from your answer and it works like a charm for me (MMA 11.3 on Win7 x64).

Comment: Hmm... seems to be fine by me too, but it rejected the many schemes I came up with before asking this question. It's odd. Maybe it prefers to parse afterwards with `Condition` over the schemes I crafted with `PatternTest` and things.

Comment: @b3m2a1 According to the Docs, `PatternTest` in `StringExpression` is applied *to every character*. So it isn't equivalent to `Condition` which is applied to the whole named pattern.

Comment: Well yes, obviously, but I remember crafting expressions that operated fine when applied with, e.g., `StringCases` or `StringMatchQ`, but which failed in `FileNames`. My guess is they couldn't be nicely condensed down to an RE or something.

Comment: @b3m2a1 It seemed to me too until I discovered that subfolders of the `$InstallationDirectory` contain files with two dots in the names. I did not test such filenames with `StringMatchQ` and `StringCases` and as a result come to illusion that `FileNames` has a bug.

Answer (score 3):

We will use a [`RegularExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html) trick since Mathematica's built-in string patterns seem to be failing.

The idea is poached from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/5720002

```
noExtRegex[ext : _String | {__String}] :=
 RegularExpression@
  TemplateApply[
   "[^\\.]*\\.((?!``).)*",
   If[Length@Flatten@{ext} > 1,
     "(" <> # <> ")" &,
     Identity
     ]@
    StringRiffle[Flatten@{ext}, "|"]
   ]
```

This will match anything of the pattern `"*.<except ext>"`.

Here's it in action:

```
FileNames[
    "*",
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
    ∞
    ] // Map[FileExtension] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort

{"", "nb", "nbp", "png", "tiff", "tr"}

FileNames[
    noExtRegex["tr"],
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
    ∞
    ] // Map[FileExtension] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort

{"nb", "nbp", "png", "tiff"}
```

We can see we dropped the `"tr"` extension. The pattern used unfortunately matches anything containing the string you supply, so we get this somewhat unfortunate result:

```
FileExtension /@
   FileNames[
    noExtRegex["n"],
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
    ∞
    ] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort

{"tiff", "tr"}
```

To make this suck less we can supply a list of the extensions we want to avoid, which then only hurts us when one extension is contained within another

```
FileExtension /@
   FileNames[
    noExtRegex[{"nb", "tr"}],
    FileNameJoin@{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd"},
    ∞
    ] // DeleteDuplicates // Sort

{"png", "tiff"}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply

```
Complement[FileNames["*",myDir], FileNames["*.<myExt>",myDir]]
```

Or would you call this "post-processing"?